# Display a ToolBar in a Xamarin.Forms modal page

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

The "new" and recommended way to display a modal page with the Xamarin.Forms Shell uri-based navigation is to set this tag in the XAML file ([source](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-shell-quick-tip-modal-navigation/)): `Shell.PresentationMode="ModalAnimated"`
and to navigate to it by using a standard route and invoking it with the function `Shell.Current.GoToAsync("routeToMyPage")`.

However, this displays the modal page without a toolbar. Without Shell navigation, I would have wrapped this page in a `NavigationPage`, but since the pages are initialized through reflection (at least that's what it looks like - don't quote me on this), I don't know how to do that.

Adding a `ToolbarItem` in the page's XAML code doesn't solve this, neither does the `Shell.NavBarIsVisible="True"` property, and adding a `Button` in the `Shell.TitleView` tag doesn't display a toolbar either.

Is there a way to display the default navigation toolbar without rendering a custom one myself?

Here is the XAML code I used to try to have the Toolbar displayed:

```
<ContentPage
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    Shell.PresentationMode="ModalAnimated"
    Shell.NavBarIsVisible="True"
    x:Class="StackOverflow.Views.MyModalPage">
    <ContentPage.ToolbarItems >
        <ToolbarItem Text="Hi"/>
    </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <Shell.TitleView>
        <Button Text="Toolbar Button"/>
    </Shell.TitleView>
    <ContentPage.Content>

    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Edit: I have created a small sample project to showcase my issue: https://github.com/Kuurse/StackOverflowExample

Answer (score 0):

You can first create the NavigationPage root page in the app class:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());
    }
}
```

Then set like this in your mainpage.xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="StackOverflow.Views.MyModalPage"
         NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="True">
<ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <ToolbarItem Text="Hi"/>
</ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
</ContentPage>
```

By the way, do you want to display only the default navigation toolbar?

Comment: I'm displaying my modal page with the `Shell.GoToAsync("myModalRoute")` function, how can I wrap my modal page in a `NavigationPage` while doing this?

Comment: I have added a sample project showing my issue and what I'm trying to do

Comment: Would you consider using Navigation directly in hidden C # files instead of in 
 the ViewModel? Because I have tried to use Navigation directly without wrapping in that case.

Comment: Or you can declare public navigation {get, set} in the viewmodel, so that you can directly use navigation.

Comment: Would these solutions allow me to use URI-based navigation to reach my modal page?

Comment: This should be OK because navigation can still be performed between pages in a Shell application by using the Navigation property. For more details about it, you may refer to this website:"https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/navigation".